# Swift 3 - Saving text when a user touches outside of a UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, swift3, notificationcenter

In Swift 3, I need to detect if the user touches outside of a UITextField, then check that a particular UITextField is the sender, and then save the text.  I have been trying to do this with Notification Center I have found examples in Swift 2, but I am struggling to implement the correct syntax for Swift 3.

```
    let notificationName = Notification.Name("UITextFieldTextDidChange")

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), name: notificationName, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)

    func textFieldDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let notification = sender as? NSNotification,
        let textFieldChanged = notification.object as? UITextField
        where textFieldChanged == self.myTextField {
        storedText = myTextField.text!
        }
    }
```

## UPDATE

I have found a slightly different way of doing this which works for me:

```
    myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

    func didChangeText(textField: UITextField) {
        if let textInField = myTextField.text {
            myTextField.text = textInField
            storedText = myTextField.text!
        }
    }
```